# How to comment a block of statements in Inno Setup?

Tags: comments, inno-setup

I am using Inno Setup 5 (Unicode).

How can a block of statements be commented/uncommented using keyboard shortcut keys?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To comment blocks of code (under the `[Code]` section) use:

- `{ commented code }` or
- `(* this is comment *)`

The Inno Setup Compiler IDE does not support shortcut keys for inserting comments.

Comment: I mean, I want to know the keyboard shortcut keys.

Comment: There is no shortcut key for this, sorry. You need to use advanced editor - like VIsual Studio or RAD Studio.

Comment: @Slappy: how can i block this whole multi lines for license related content? please see: http://paste.ubuntu.com/10704066/

Comment: In [Code] section you can use (* comment *) Outside it comment every line with semicolon ;

Answer (score 10):

The correct comment character is a semicolon - like this:

```
; This is a note
```

You can use other methods - however, they will show as underlined in red.  But a semicolon with nothing to the left of it (except white space) will turn the line green.

So if you have a line like this:

```
Source: distrib_v2.9\vcredist_x86.exe; DestDir: {sys}; Flags: ignoreversion 32bit;
```

and you put a semicolon in front of that line like this:

```
;Source: distrib_v2.9\vcredist_x86.exe; DestDir: {sys}; Flags: ignoreversion 32bit;
```

Then the entire line turns green as a comment.

There is no shortcut key that I know of.  Since it is only one character, I don't think a shortcut key is needed.

Note that the left and right curly brackets {} are used for constants in Inno Setup. I do not recommend that you use them for comments. An example is {app} or {sys}.  These are not treated as comments.

Comment: The OP was apparently asking about Pascal Scripting code (`[Code]` section), not regular Inno Setup sections.

Comment: Ok. I didn't catch that at first. Slappy caught that idea and answered perfectly above.